# If a keyword is found in list

Tags: python

```
import requests
K=0
site = ['example.com', 'example.com']
url = ("https://"+ (str(site[K])))
r = requests.get(url)
keywords = ['abc','nice','test']

if keywords in r.text.lower():
   print('done')
   K +=1
```

Getting error: TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Comment: That's weird. It should say "not list".

Answer (score 1):

Use `any`:

```
if any(kw in r.text.lower() for kw in keywords):
    print('done')
```

Or use `re`:

```
import re

if re.search('|'.join(keywords), r.text.lower()):
    print('done')
```